# R: Create indicator variables from data and extract category

Tags: r, categorical-data, dummy-variable, indicator

I have a data frame `df` that stores the average height in cm of several thousand plants in different years:

```
Name    Year    Height
Plant1  2010    440
Plant2  2011    60
Plant1  2011    1980
Plant3  2013    650
Plant4  2016    210
```

I want to do the following:

a) Create a variable for every height interval of 50 cm between 400 cm and 2000 cm (inclusive) with two variables <400 and >2000. `df` should look like this:

```
Name    Year    Height h_0_400 h_400 h_450 h_500 h_550 etc.
Plant1  2010    440    
Plant2  2011    60
Plant1  2011    1980
Plant3  2013    640
Plant4  2016    210
```

b) Assign the variables 0 or 1 depending on the actual `height`:

```
Name    Year    Height h_0_400 h_400 h_450 h_500 h_550 etc.
Plant1  2010    440    0       1     0     0     0
Plant2  2011    60     1       0     0     0     0
Plant1  2011    1980   0       0     0     0     0
Plant3  2013    640    0       0     0     0     0
Plant4  2016    210    1       0     0     0     0
```

c) Add a variable that indicates which category of `heights` the entry belongs to

```
Name    Year    Height h_0_400 h_400 h_450 h_500 h_550 etc. height_index
Plant1  2010    440    0       1     0     0     0          h_400
Plant2  2011    60     1       0     0     0     0          h_0_400
Plant1  2011    1980   0       0     0     0     0          h_1950
Plant3  2013    640    0       0     0     0     0          h_600
Plant4  2016    210    1       0     0     0     0          h_0_400
```

I am not sure how to approach the problem and would appreciate any insight. So far, I've tried to work with `seq(400,2000,by=1)` and drop the values that are not needed, but that seems very inefficient.
I am happy to work with any package. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option is to use `cut` (or using `findInterval`) to create a variable group and then reshape to wide format

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
out <- df %>%
   # // create grouping variable with cut based on the Height
   mutate(ind = cut(Height, breaks = c(-Inf, c(0, seq(400, 2000,
          by = 50 ))), labels = c('h_0_400', 
  str_c('h_', seq(400, 2000, by = 50)))), height_index = ind, n = 1)  %>%
   # // reshape to wide format
   pivot_wider(names_from = ind, values_from = n, values_fill= list(n = 0))

# // missing columns are created with setdiff and assigned to 0
out[setdiff(levels(out$height_index), out$height_index)] <- 0
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Name = c("Plant1", "Plant2", "Plant1", "Plant3", 
"Plant4"), Year = c(2010L, 2011L, 2011L, 2013L, 2016L), Height = c(340L, 
60L, 1980L, 650L, 210L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll give it a shot right away! What is 'ind'?

Comment: @questionmark it is just a temporary variable created with the `cut` which will go as the column names in `pivot_wider`

Comment: That's very helpful, thank you! Do you know why the variable count doesn't change?

Comment: Sorry, that was ambiguous. Running dim(df) before and after your code gives me the same result/same number of variables. I am not sure why that is the case and was wondering if you knew.

Comment: @questionmark my output object is `out`.  I didn't update the 'df' in place

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do this in base R :

```
#Create a sequence
vals <- seq(400, 2000, 50)
#Create column names
cols <- paste('h', c(0, vals[-length(vals)]), vals, sep = "_")
#Initialize new columns with 0
df[cols] <- 0
#Find which interval the height lies 
inds <- findInterval(df$Height, vals) + 1
#Make the respective column as 1
df[cols][cbind(1:nrow(df), inds)] <- 1
#Create a new column giving the column name
df$height_index <- cols[inds]
```

The final dataframe looks like this :

```
df
#    Name Year Height h_0_400 h_400_450 h_450_500 h_500_550 h_550_600
#1 Plant1 2010    440       0         1         0         0         0
#2 Plant2 2011     60       1         0         0         0         0
#3 Plant1 2011   1980       0         0         0         0         0
#4 Plant3 2013    650       0         0         0         0         0
#5 Plant4 2016    210       1         0         0         0         0
#  h_600_650 h_650_700 h_700_750 h_750_800 h_800_850 h_850_900 h_900_950
#1         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
#2         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
#3         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
#4         0         1         0         0         0         0         0
#5         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
#  h_950_1000 h_1000_1050 h_1050_1100 h_1100_1150 h_1150_1200 h_1200_1250
#1          0           0           0           0           0           0
#2          0           0           0           0           0           0
#3          0           0           0           0           0           0
#4          0           0           0           0           0           0
#5          0           0           0           0           0           0
#  h_1250_1300 h_1300_1350 h_1350_1400 h_1400_1450 h_1450_1500 h_1500_1550
#1           0           0           0           0           0           0
#2           0           0           0           0           0           0
#3           0           0           0           0           0           0
#4           0           0           0           0           0           0
#5           0           0           0           0           0           0
#  h_1550_1600 h_1600_1650 h_1650_1700 h_1700_1750 h_1750_1800 h_1800_1850
#1           0           0           0           0           0           0
#2           0           0           0           0           0           0
#3           0           0           0           0           0           0
#4           0           0           0           0           0           0
#5           0           0           0           0           0           0
#  h_1850_1900 h_1900_1950 h_1950_2000 height_index
#1           0           0           0    h_400_450
#2           0           0           0      h_0_400
#3           0           0           1  h_1950_2000
#4           0           0           0    h_650_700
#5           0           0           0      h_0_400
```

Comment: Great base R approach! Thank you, Ronak!